# What are the signs of a successful Homa?

Tags: homam

I read somewhere that there are certain 'Signs' which indicate whether a Homa was success or not - but the signs were not specified.
What are these signs?

Comment: If the aim of a Homa is realized or evidenced on its performance then the Homa can be said to be successful or effective. Like rain appearing if Homa was  for rains. If homa is done for removal of Covid and nothing happened thereafter then one may say it was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

In KaliYuga the signs may not be depicted or realised and often it may be false only. Offerings are secrets to God and no human can understand them. Many just follow what ancestors did.

Successful homam results in auspicious power to seeker provided the seeker is non-sinner. If sinner, must perform homam according to Kaala vidhi to please Gods. The pleasance of Gods can be felt even in KaliYuga.